# How to get the blog post's featured image, content, last modified date and comments count?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have a wordpress site in which I want to create a blog page which will display the following things.

1. The blog's featured image in first line
2. The blog title in the second line
3. The blog content(text) in the third line
4. The last update, comments count and posted by in the 4th line.

How will I do this?

Shoud I directly query the database or use some builtin functions?

Any help?

Comment: please move this question to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( );
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if( has_post_thumbnail())
        the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );
        else {
        $photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );
            if ($photos) {
                $photo = array_shift($photos);
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, 'medium' );
            }
        }

        echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>'; 
        the_excerpt();

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query();
```